# AWS Greengrass Docker Container Publish MQTT to the IoT Cloud

Tags: docker, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-iot-greengrass

We have a Greengrass V1 group setup with a bunch of lambda functions and a few docker containers deployed using the docker connector. The docker containers are mostly Node.js REST APIs that are used by the lambda functions.

Until now we've never had a reason for these docker containers to communicate with the IoT cloud - they only ever send REST responses back to the calling lambda functions. But now we have the need for a docker container to perform a task and send an MQTT message back to the cloud.

I'm having a little trouble getting the right docs on how to do this. I think I need be using the aws-iot-device-sdk-js (since this will be a Node.js REST API in the docker image). But I don't see how the [examples](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js/tree/master/examples) in that repo apply if I'm using the docker connector in a Greengrass group.

Comment: You need to use greengrass sdk. here is an example: https://github.com/aws/aws-greengrass-core-sdk-js/blob/master/greengrassExamples/HelloWorld/index.js

Also, you need to setup your greengrass core properly so it can transfer mqtt messages to aws iot cloud: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/v1/developerguide/config-lambda.html

I would highly suggest to migrate to greengrass v2 which is much simpler to setup and deploy application.